# Animate the insertion of a new section in UITableVIew

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I have this button on my view, and when I press it I insert a new section in my table view ( I have a logical condition in my

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    if (slide==TRUE) return 2;
    return 1;
}
```

And also in my `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. My section is added as it should, but I have read somewhere that this can be animated, because when I press my button the section is added but with no animation. I think I should use this `-(void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet*)sections withRowanimation(UITableViewRowAnimation) animation` but I haven't found a proper example on the web.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`UITableViewRowAnimation` is an enum declared at the top of UITableView.h You can also view it in the [UITableView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's smallish, so I'll just paste it!

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewRowAnimationFade,
    UITableViewRowAnimationRight,           // slide in from right (or out to right)
    UITableViewRowAnimationLeft,
    UITableViewRowAnimationTop,
    UITableViewRowAnimationBottom,
    UITableViewRowAnimationNone,            // available in iOS 3.0
    UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle,          // available in iOS 3.2.  attempts to keep cell centered in the space it will/did occupy
    UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic = 100  // available in iOS 5.0.  chooses an appropriate animation style for you
} UITableViewRowAnimation;
```

Basically it tells the table view from which direction you want the rows/sections to be animated in/out. A little experimenting will demonstrate the effect of each.

For example, inserting a row with `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` will trigger an animation which gives the impression of a row coming into the table view from a space immediately above that of its final destination in the table view.

So your insertion might look like:

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(id)slider {
   slide = slider.on;

   [tableView beginUpdates];

   if (slider.on) {
      [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
      // TODO: update data model by inserting new section
   } else {
      [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
      // TODO: update data model by removing approprite section
   }

   [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

And you will have to be sure that your delegate and data source provide info that is consistent with your assertion to insert sections/rows. From your question, it looks like you have done so.

EDITS:

I don't *think* you have to call `reloadData`. `UITableView` requires that your data model reflect the changes you make with with the insert/delete methods. So that, for example, if, before a call to `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` (with which you are inserting a single section), your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method returned 1, then, after the call, it *must* return 2. To do otherwise throws an exception. It is this enforcement of consistency that allows you (again, I *think*) to avoid the call to `reloadData` - the necessary data is being reloaded by the whole `beginUpdates:` `endUpdates:` transaction, and any updates to the model you make during that transaction must match one-for-one your insert/delete calls.

Clear as mud?

UPDATES

If you were programming explicit animations, then I would say that you could do it in the 'completion handler' (or just program the animation directly for that matter), but that is not available to you here. I think you can wrap the button-presenting code in its own method in the view, then set a timer to call it after a short amount of time, say, .2 seconds (you'll have to experiment to see what looks good). e.g.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.2 target:self selector:@selector(presentButton) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not at my Mac right now, so I can't test it, but this seems pretty clear to me, and I strongly believe it will work. Also, if I call `insertSections` do I still need to call `reloadData` ?

Comment: Yeap, this is as clear as it gets. After I test this, I will let you know how it went. Thank you for your help, your answer was really good.

Comment: This code is missing the calls to `UITableView`'s `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods, so it won't work.  Also, it is important to update your data model somewhere between the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls.  Lastly, there is no point to do animation if you call `reloadData` as this will reload all the data and re-render any visible tableview cells based on the new table data.  So, **if you want animation, do not call `reloadData`**.

Comment: Edited. And thanks for your confidence regarding `reloadData:` I wasn't sure about it.

Comment: Worked great, thanks a lot. I have one more question, is there anyway I can call a method after the animation ended? I want to add a button on the view but It adds it while the animation is running.

Answer (score 34):

Manipulating rows and sections into UITableView using animation is made pretty easy using the following API's (emphasis on the last two):

- [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38)
- [`insertSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW22)
- [`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW39)
- [`deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW23)
- **[`beginUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW15)**
- **[`endUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW14)**

### Updating the Data Model

You should update your data model anywhere between the [`beginUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW15) and [`endUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW14) methods.  It doesn't matter if you update your data model before or after insertion or deletion methods just so long as you do it between the [`beginUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW15) and [`endUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW14) methods.

### Do not Insert Rows for New Sections You are Inserting

When adding a new section using the [`insertSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW22) method, you do not need to call [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38) to add rows into it.  The [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38) method is just for animating an existing section changing.  Similarly, you do not need to call [`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW39) when you remove a section using [`deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW23).

### Regarding Deleting and Inserting:

I generally do these in separate [`beginUpdates:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW15) [`endUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW14) calls, however you can insert and delete at the same time.  Just be aware that the UITableView will **first** try to delete rows / sections and **then** try to insert them *regardless of the order you do it in your code*.

**Discussion** part of [`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW39)

> Note the behavior of this method when it is called in an animation
>   block defined by the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods. UITableView
>   defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled
>   the deletions of rows or sections. This happens regardless of ordering
>   of the insertion and deletion method calls. This is unlike inserting
>   or removing an item in a mutable array, where the operation can affect
>   the array index used for the successive insertion or removal
>   operation. For more on this subject, see “Batch Insertion and Deletion
>   of Rows and Sections” in Table View Programming Guide for iOS.

### Example of inserting into a section:

```
int indexOfNewSection = 4; // TODO: change to meaningful value
[self.tableview beginUpdates];
[self.tableview insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexOfNewSection]
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

// Update data model
[self.sections insertObject:sectionObj atIndex:indexOfNewSection];

[self.tableview endUpdates];
```

Comment: Also, calling `UITableView`'s `reloadData` method is not necessary when animating the insertion / deletion of rows and sections.  Calling `reload` data will reload all cells and rows in view (with no animation).  Also, my example is from working code with very little modifiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. I have one more question, is there any way I can call a method when the animation has finished?

Comment: @Cosmin Unfortunately I am not aware of any callbacks or completion blocks for any of the `UITableView` animated change events.  You can open this up as a new question on SO to see if other community members know how to do that.

Comment: Reference to your post. Can I ask one question related to adding section?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

This method pointed out by will definitely do the magic.

Probably you can try this:

```
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Writing straight out of my mind.. hope this helps...

Please note:

1. Any of the `UITableViewRowAnimation` can be used.
2. `sectionIndex` in the mentioned code is an NSInteger. Probably in your case 1.

Comment: Reference to your post. Can I ask one question related to adding section?