# How to add new section in group UITableView like adding new rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, insert

Ive been googling around but I couldn't find any straight tutorials or answers about this so I decided to ask.

I understand and am able to insert new rows to a group uitableview with `insertRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation`.

What I would like to do now is rather than insert new rows, I want to insert new sections, each section containing 2 rows.

How can I do this, or what should I look into?

---

What I've tried:

An NSMutableArray `self.objectArray`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.objectArray.count;
}
```

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I did this:

```
UITextField *itemNameTextField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    NSString *itemName = self.objectArray[indexPath.section][@"itemName"];
    [itemNameTextField setText:itemName];
    [itemNameTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(updateItemName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

I have a bar button item that calls `addItemBarBtnTapped:` when tapped:

```
- (IBAction)addItemBarBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Create item object.
    NSMutableDictionary *itemObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    itemObject[@"itemName"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", self.billItemsArray.count+1];
    itemObject[@"itemPrice"] = @"0";
    itemObject[@"itemSharersArray"] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Add itemObject to objectArray, which reflects the new number of sections, and reloadData to reflect changes.
    [self.objectArray addObject:itemObject];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This is what I am doing currently, and it works because I see the value in the textFields in my cells having the correct values e.g. Item 1, Item 2 etc. (These values are set and stored in the data source at `addItemBarBtnTapped`.

However, I don't think this is the right way to "add sections to a tableView", it's missing the "animation", and I wish to add 2 rows per section, each time I add the section.

---

I can't find an answer relating to my problem nor are there any tutorial about adding sections on the Internet so I'll really appreciate the help from you guys!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:

```
 int indexOfNewSection = self.objectArray.count; 
    [self.tableview beginUpdates];
    [self.tableview insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexOfNewSection]
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    // Update data model
     itemObject[@"itemName"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", self.billItemsArray.count+1];
        itemObject[@"itemPrice"] = @"0";
        itemObject[@"itemSharersArray"] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.objectArray insertObject:sectionObj atIndex:indexOfNewSection];

    [self.tableview endUpdates];
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the insertSections method above. The problem is I don't know how this whole mechanism works and I don't know which direction to go from here. I know I'm definitely getting an error if i just to a `[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482072/animate-the-insertion-of-a-new-section-in-uitableview

Comment: I've seen that question before I posted this. That question is basically asking how to insert a new ROW rather than a section.

Comment: Yes, the code above is working logically but it doesn't have animation. I don't think that it is the right way of "inserting a section" too.

Comment: Great! Inserting of new sections are now working (with some edits)! `int indexOfNewSection = self.objectArray.count` worked without the `+1` (Maybe you can update your correct answer?). And in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I all needed to do was change indexPath.row to indexPath.section for the datasource to be working properly. Thanks!